# Locate character at given position in a string

Tags: mysql

If I have a string stored in column x = "Hello"

How can I do something like like select x[2]

This would return "l" because position 2 in the string hello is l

Comment: [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) show substr or substring  Lots of string functions out there so the docs may help you learn about other options which may aid you now or in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Substring**

Substring(String Value, Starting Position, Length from starting position)

```
declare @meme varchar(100) = 'Hello'
select SUBSTRING(@meme,2,1)
```

Output:

> e

For use in a select statement from a table, you could use like so:

```
SELECT TOP 100
SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 5,3)
FROM TableName
```

**Left**

You can select a string from the left to right like so:

```
select left(@meme,3)
```

Output:

> Hel

**Right**

Similarly to left, you can select from the right to left in the same way:

```
select right(@meme,3)
```

Output:

> oll